# Trying to get a COMPLETE list of AWS Route53 records. How to get more than the first 100?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am trying to list records on route53 that we have but am failing to get more than the first 100 results! How can I list ALL of them? How can I also filter the results to list only those with a specific RecordType?

This is the code I tried running but I fail to get a complete list…:

```
string recordList = "";
int ii = 0;
ListResourceRecordSetsResponse result = r53client.ListResourceRecordSets(request);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(result.ListResourceRecordSetsResult.ResourceRecordSets.Count+" records!");
while (result.ListResourceRecordSetsResult.ResourceRecordSets.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var recordSet in result.ListResourceRecordSetsResult.ResourceRecordSets)
    {
        if (recordSet.Type == "CNAME")
        {
            foreach (var resourceRecord in recordSet.ResourceRecords)
            {

                recordList += resourceRecord.Value + "\n";
                jj++;
                // set first record to get next, as the last one we already got!
                request.StartRecordName = resourceRecord.Value;
            }

        }
    }
result = r53client.ListResourceRecordSets(request);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From [Github: Can you get more than 100 ListResourceRecordSets](https://github.com/chilts/awssum-amazon-route53/issues/2):

> If the response says `IsTruncated` is true, then you need to pass the values of `NextRecordType`, `NextRecordName`, and `NextRecordIdentifier` back to a new call.

From [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) documentation for [`list-resource-record-sets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html):

> To retrieve all the records in a HostedZone, first pause any processes making calls to `ChangeResourceRecordSets`. Initially call list-resource-record-sets without a Name and Type to get the first page of record sets. For subsequent calls, set `Name` and `Type` to the `NextName` and `NextType` values returned by the previous response.

From [Class ListResourceRecordSetsRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/route53/model/ListResourceRecordSetsResult.html):

> To retrieve all the records in a HostedZone, first pause any processes making calls to ChangeResourceRecordSets. Initially call `ListResourceRecordSets` without a Name and Type to get the first page of record sets. For subsequent calls, set `Name` and `Type` to the `NextName` and `NextType` values returned by the previous response.

Comment: Jhon, if you take a look at the piece of code above, this is exactly what I did! set the request.StartRecordName to the last one I got but the next call to ListResourceRecordSets does not seem to work and bring the NEXT set! ideas?

Comment: Looks like you should use `IsTruncated` rather than `Count > 0`, but more importantly, set `startRecordType` to the next value, too.